# How can I convert string '1234-2345' to integer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

How can I convert a string to integer?

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(30)='1234-2345'
```

How can I convert @string to integer type?

Comment: To which number do you want `1234-2345` to be converted?

Comment: I want the string as it is in my integer. its not possible right?

Comment: So you want to have 12342345 as result?

Comment: So should result be `12342345` (just strip off any non-digits), or `-1111` (as a result of subtraction)?

Comment: Do you want 1) 1234, or 2) 12342345, or 3) 2345, or 4) -1111 (i.e 1234 minus 2345)?

Comment: I need 1234-2345 where - is a symbol

Comment: The problem is, it's still not clear what you mean - it's like asking how to convert the colour blue to an integer. Integers are whole numbers. They don't "contain" symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the dash and cast the result as integer. `SELECT CAST(REPLACE('1234-2345','-','') as int)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you need:

```
DECLARE @Result INT
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(30)='1234-2345'
SELECT @Result = CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(@string, '-', ''))

SELECT @Result --Your desired result
```

If you want the result of your expression:

```
DECLARE @Result INT
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(30)='1234-2345'

SELECT  @Result = CAST(LEFT(@string, CHARINDEX('-', @string) - 1) AS INT) -
                  CAST(RIGHT(@string, CHARINDEX('-', @string) - 1) AS INT)

SELECT @Result --Your desired result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 1234 *minus* 2345 then

```
SELECT CAST((1234-2345) AS INT)
SELECT CAST((@string) AS INT)
```

If mean remove the `-` sign then

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('1234-2345','-','') as int)
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@string,'-','') as int)
```

Comment: If @string is '1234-2345' then `SELECT CAST((@string) AS INT)` will not work. Actually your first snippet `SELECT CAST((1234-2345) AS INT)` is working just because `1234-2345` is already result of subtraction, and there is no conversion from any string here.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to remove '-' from string then you can use replace function 
and cast it to int type.
 As Follow :

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(30)='1234-2345'

SELECT CAST(REPLACE('1234-2345','-','') as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment:

> I need 1234-2345 where - is a symbol

It is not possible.  The integer datatype cannot contain any symbol characters.

Answer (score 0):

Some out of the box thinking.  Now the string become a math problem with the result cast as an int.

```
DECLARE 
 @STR NVARCHAR(50) = N'12345-235',
 @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
 @PRAMS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@RETURN AS INT OUTPUT'

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @RETURN = CAST((' + @STR + N') AS INT)'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL , @PRAMS, @RETURN = @RETURNED OUTPUT

SELECT @RETURNED
```